# Should I use Resharper to tidy up other peoples code?

Tags: .net, refactoring, resharper, maintainability

I use Resharper at work.  Some of my colleagues do not.

When I open some code that has been written someone who doesn't, it is immediately obvious by the amount of orange on my screen.

What I am unsure of is to what extent I should feel free to tidy up the messes the have unknowingly left.  With most of what I am looking at, it is sloppy but harmless, and wouldn't really jump out at me if I hadn't ever used Resharper.

I guess I see my options broadly as

1) The history of changes to source code is essential to maintenance.  Change as little as possible, or the next guy wont have a hope of figuring out what has changed.  Who cares about unreachable code, unnecessary use of .ToString() etc. anyway.

2) Change the meaningless stuff like includes, fix method documentation comments and things like that.  The guy who wrote it likes his code to look like this, so leave it in a state where he wont complain, but get rid of some of the unnecessary orange

3) Orange is just red but lighter.  F12 then Alt+Enter until green.

4) Forget the orange, look at that monster 700 line function.  What is this 1997?  Time to get busy...  and if you have got the time, introduce your colleague to our good friend and mentor Mr Fowler.

I tend to flit between the options depending on how much time I have got, to what extent I am now responsible for the code, and how complex the code looks (which can make me go for 1 or 4 usually).

It seems like one of the 4 options should be the one I am striving for though, but I have no idea which one

Comment: seems like you're answering your own question by just doing what you can when you can.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't comment after drinking a bottle of wine, but it seems insane to me that people seem more worried about offending their "teammate" than the 700 line function?  It looks like alchohol turns me into a purist jerk.

Comment: <sarcasm>Yes!  Use Resharper to clean other people's code, especially when you leave Resharper at its default settings and it strips out all of their pretty comments.</sarcasm>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
"Leave the campsite cleaner than you found it."
```

It's the boyscout principle.  If it's "their" code and they maintain it then introducing little cleanup-changes shouldn't offend them, but going too far might seem rude or you might be effectively taking ownership of the code.

Comment: I recently overheard a developer saying "well I can't really help you.  The code has totally changed since I last looked at it".  I think who has the ownership going forwards is a very good point

Comment: @Modan, i recommend you to replace explicit type declarations with "var"s (through cleanup for whole solution) and devilishly laugh at them. they love it! :)

Comment: That said, resharper sometimes wants to turn an intricate `forEach` construction into one big, long, hardly readable line of Linq.
Whenever it wants to do that, i turn the notification off by comment and add a note that the code below is less readable as Linq.

Comment: Little cleanup is the smartest thing a team can do collaborately.  Why keep code in a sloppy state especially when you can use ReSharper Hints to easily and quickly refactor small parts...example using ?? or ?:, etc.  or removing unnecessary else statements.  This just makes the code more readable if anything...less lines of code means easier to maintain.  Cleaner is always better so a team should at all times strive for it.  Otherwise the business NEVER gives you that "project to go.  The Boyscout rule applies to anything not just code.

Comment: Code changes...deal with it.  Otherwise you're not a developer if you can't jump in and handle change...if that code has changed for the better, is easier to read, or whatever then you should be inviting this change, not condemming it.  Why read a 100 line method which is total slop when you can refactor that puppy without breaking anything?  It should be expected not questioned.

Answer (score 15):

Your team should agree on a standard.  If someone else uses another tool, you may find yourself in an unintentional edit war.

But if you can all agree, then yes.  Clean up the code as you go.

Answer (score 6):

I do a "reformat" check in before changing any of the actual logic, this way you can see what has changed.

Comment: That's nice for a diff, but when you go to do an SVN Blame to see who made what change, you're name will be everywhere.

Comment: @Alan :) I think that the idea is that everyone in the team should do reformat before check-in.

Comment: You can always use the commit hook to compare the submitted code with the same code run through the formatter. If the two aren't identical, the commit fails with a notice.

This ensures that all code will be formatted before submission (or that your developers will moan and complain and then figure out how to bypass the hook).

Answer (score 5):

Needless refactoring is just that - needless.  It clutters up the repository history logs and you can introduce bugs.

If the "meaningless" stuff (documentation, comments, etc.) is supposed to be formatted a certain way, and it's not up to your development standards, then I would do it all at once in as few checkins as possible.

When you are actually working on the pieces of code and have the opportunity to test your changes, do the refactoring then.  Resharper will always be available to show you the way at that point.

Comment: Yea, but not everyone cares about code in the same way. Some people are perfectly content to "shit where they eat" so to speak.

Comment: Managers shouldn't let people sh*t where they eat. If you have a problem with the quality of code in your team, the best approach is to talk to your manager about it, rather than telling other people you think their work is sh*t (and that yours is better) by refactoring it on their behalf.

Comment: @Jason - yes.  And may I add "needlessly refactoring it on their behalf".  Unless there is an identified problem with their code (a bug, code standards problem, whatever), refactoring it is needless and make-work, no matter how much it offends you personally as a coder.

Answer (score 2):

If the development tools in your team are not the same eventually there will be even more trouble. Follow the "reformat" check-in suggested above and standardize the toolset with your colleagues, either drop resharper or give everyone the formatting magic wand.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you change anything, regardless of the intent, you risk breaking something unintentionally.  On a personal side, I wouldn't change another person's code without talking to them first.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend only changing things when you need to.  There is, of course, some varying definition on what "need" means.  For example, if you write a method that calls another method, and this method you're calling happens to have some code duplication?  I'd refactor that, and while I'm at it remove excess `using` statements, etc.  I'd try to avoid just a massive refactor of the entire codebase "just because" though.

Answer (score 1):

If it's already checked in, be careful.  Some people get awfully touchy and it's considered rude if someone on your team is still using tools from a decade ago that can't disable whitespace detection during a diff.

In general, I'll clean up code styling to bring it in line with the stated organization style goals when I'm touching the code for another reason.  Try to remember that style is style, however, and as such there is no "one true way."  Don't make enemies because you don't like the fact that a colleague uses less (or more) whitespace than you do.

Comment: My version of GNU diff was built in 2002 (3 years shy of decade, but still), and it can detect and ignore whitespace just fine, thank you. I set up SVN to use that particular diff and all is well in the world.

Comment: Sometimes whitespace is significant, so not everyone likes to switch off whitespace detection. (BTW my diff tool is from 1996 and it can ignore whitespace too. )

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be that if you do a reformat that it be done separately from any code modifications.  The reason for this is that you can mark it as "reformat only" in the repository and a legitimate code change will not be buried in the middle of a bunch of spacing changes making it impossible for you or the next guy to figure out what broke.

Answer (score 1):

As the majority of people have already said, yes, better to refactor and leave it tidier.

Refactoring helps everyone get better, and everyone should have access to the refactoring tools (Coderush for me).

However, if your colleagues aren't sharing the refactoring love, then it's a good opportunity for you to enlighten them :)